# How to switch between "Document Groups" in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, editor, visual-studio-2022

I have several `Document Groups` open in Visual Studio 2022 (C++) and would like to quickly switch the cursor between them with a keyboard command. However, all found under `Tools->Options` was

- Window.NextDocumentWindow (switches between recently opened windows)
- Window.NextDocumentWindowNav (opens another window)
- Window.NextTab (moves within one Document Group)
- Window.MovetoNextTabGroup ("Move to Next Document Group" - moves the cursor but also the window with it)

None of them do what I have in mind - simply going to the left/right "document group".

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This was bothering me as well couple of years ago, so I switched to VsVim, I can simply move around with ctrl+w j,k,l,h. Switching with with ctrl+tab is too slow. I don't know how is this not implemented in VS up until now. Did you request a feature maybe ?

Comment: Hmm, I'm just a lowly peasant. I would not even know where to request a feature. But also, I thought it was such an obvious thing that surely it must either be implemented or left out on purpose.

Comment: Looks like someone requested it already. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cannot-navigate-between-document-groups/1295079
You can request a feature from within visual studio or from this portal that I sent